# Example of creating an in-memory sqlite db in Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How do I create an in-memory sqlite db in Java (Android)? The sqlite docs only show how to do it in C.

I am using the android.database.sqlite package for my db code so I'd prefer to do it with that package, if possible.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it in the same way you'd create any database but instead of passing in a name pass in NULL

for example, in your OpenHelper you'd do something like:

```
OpenHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, null, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

more info on SQLiteOpenHelper [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29)

Comment: D'oh! I should have seen that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[This is](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) the offical reference, Good Luck!